# Works on philosophy and television?

Tags: epistemology, reference-request, philosophy-of-mind

There seem to be many works on "Philosophy and..." this or that popular TV show; philosophical takes on the ethical contents of tv shows; and works on television in critical theory, pop culture, and media studies, after than manner of the Frankfurt School.

But are there any good philosophical theories that incorporate the advent of "television" (in the largest, interactive sense) into a deeper, perhaps epistemological or phenomenological treatment? Something more like Hegel's treatment of art and history.

Perhaps I am missing a whole genre of philosophical work, but television seems so radical and fundamental to the Zeitgeist as to warrant a bigger place in the literature. Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps Jean Baudrillard - The Ecstasy of Communication. I'm not sure though if it fits your criteria.

Comment: Thanks, actually I forgot all about Baudrillard. Maybe I'll check and see how well he ages.

Comment: i dislike your trivialisation of critical theory, but a genuine "phenomenology of television" would be fun

Comment: you could try tracking down this https://www.asc.upenn.edu/news-events/events/introduction-phenomenology-television-what-happens-when-i-turn-tv-set

or chapter five of Television and the Moral Imaginary: Society Through the Small Screen... etc.

Comment: Television is so last century. I'll do you better, Dreyfus wrote a book on philosophy of Internet http://cryptome.org/2013/01/aaron-swartz/On-the-Internet.pdf  But if you insist here is Nuncio:"the transition from modern to postmodern. From location to bilocation and virtual location—the entire route of cultural turns has made the possibility of postmodern regimented bodies through the television". http://ejournals.ph/index.php?journal=PIJP&page=article&op=viewArticle&path[]=286

Comment: Thanks all for refs. I know TV is "last century" but somehow even more basic turn than Internet, I think. I actually tend to collapse both terms to "screen." And to me "old TV" is technologically stranger because it is "in the airwaves." Old Ed Sullivan Shows, etc., are actually "there" in the same electromagnetic time and space you occupy.

Comment: Jacques Ellul. https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=GwtscHfNtaw If you understand French. He wrote a book on television too 70s or 80s date. Will have in English in American university libraries.  Wikipedia on him you may want to read.

Comment: Also Guy DeBord has to be given a lot of credit for seeing the danger of the “new media” or media wall in general. He wrote Society of the Spectacle. Not a very mature book.  The Situationists has already influenced the students of 1968. Later Debord wrote Comment on the Society of the Spectacle, which is a better book. Available on Internet Archive.

Comment: Pierre Bourdieu wrote about television, particularly as a need media. Although he was a sociologist rather than a philosopher, FYI https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://monoskop.org/images/1/13/Bourdieu_Pierre_On_Television.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjonNjokafuAhVKPHAKHabjDUkQFjAAegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw1uluxX-s68ST8DXhKA1ZOL

Answer (score 1):

Not as related to formal philosophical discourse as critical theory, David Foster Wallace's famous essay E Unibus Pluram is a great analysis on TV culture.

Comment: I wish those who had marked this down 2 had given some explanation. I have not read this book but to have 2 negative votes when I came along, this seems excessive to me.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, there is a text by Popper on TV.

The french translation is " La lélévision, un danger pour la démocratie".

I cannot find the original reference in english.

Also, Boudieu ( a sociologist with a philosophical academic background) :

https://monoskop.org/images/1/13/Bourdieu_Pierre_On_Television.pdf

Answer (score 1):

While he did not write *specifically* about television I highly suggest Guy Deboard's "The Society of the Spectacle".

Marshall McLuhan was the man who coined the phrase, "The medium is the message". He believed that the medium of communication (television in this case) shaped the message being delivered. And so if you look into his writings you should absolutely be able to find something about television.